# Start buttons on an angle?

Tags: android, button, angle

I have some buttons that I'd like to be at a downward angle on my UI.  Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: there is a method `setRotation(float degrees)` on Button. see docs. you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see that method on buttons in code. Searching for setRotation online seems to bring up display and camera more than anything.  Not sure it can be used for a button.

Comment: You can create an imageview button by using a transparent png as its background. You would have to desing it first.

Comment: sorry. this method seems to be available only on API 11. link - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is with a custom view.

Comment: Booo. Hisss. Well, that's unfortunate. An animation can rotate, I thought maybe it could just be partially rotated and then stop in position. Any ideas on how to create a custom button at an angle?  Thanks